# Common Understanding?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for "common understanding"? I am trying to find a single word that describes a common understanding of values inside an organization.

The company's values are widely recognized by all employees.

All of the employees have a common understanding of the company's values.

Comment: If I tell you that you have described _corporate culture_, two words, can you use that, or does that break your rules?

Comment: _Consensus_ is the usual noun. _Consensual_ is the adjective. it means 'shared sense'.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said: *culture*. Or *ideology*...

Answer (score 1):

If you rework your sentence a bit, you can use ***share*** instead of using *have a common understanding*.

> All of the employees ***share*** the company's values.

One of the definitions of ***share*** is:

> :  to have in common <*they share a passion for opera*>
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/share)</sub>